# Is there a way to undock the assistant editor in Xcode into its own window or onto a second monitor

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to have one assistant editor (on my second monitor for example) which always shows the counterpart to the file which I am currently editing (on my first monitor)?

I can create a new tab, drag it out into its own window and show the assistant editor but of course it doesn't show the counterpart to the file I am editing on my primary window/monitor.

Is there any way to make it do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't. But you can always send feedback to apple regarding what you'd like to see in future updates. If this request comes from many devs, maybe there is a chance to see it added to xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed.  With the focus on multi-monitor support this is a feature that has been missing.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7.3, I just double click a file in the Project Navigator view and a new editor window with the file is opened.